# TimeManager: "Have layers, but animation not possible"

Tags: qgis, timemanager

I have used TimeManager before and really like however I have some problem now with QGIS 2.18.4 (can't pinpoint the problem to 2.18.4)

However, I use a PostgreSQL/PostGIS layer as input

[image: PostgreSQL print screen]
I've tried to cast the time to time zone with/without time zone. QGIS recognises the type:

[image: QGIS types]

TimeManager manage to get the time as well:

[image: Timemangaer print screen]

But I got the error "Have layers, but animation not possible".
I've tried with the field "time_" instead, I've tried with the timeformat: %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S, %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S, %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+01

Any suggestion what I shall change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only source of this error is in [timemanagercontrol.py](https://github.com/anitagraser/TimeManager/blob/66f6dff12b1513209f199dadc16260f8c8dfb672/timemanagercontrol.py)

```
    expectedNumberOfFrames = self.timeLayerManager.getFrameCount()
    if expectedNumberOfFrames == 0:  # will be zero if no layer is time managed
        self.animationActivated = False
        if len(self.getTimeLayerManager().getTimeLayerList()) > 0:
            error("Have layers, but animation not possible")
```

Which time range does your data cover? Could it be less than a minute? All lines in the screenshot are on 09:47:xx ...

Try changing the time frame size unit to seconds.

Comment: I found that aswell. I tried to change it with no success, when I import the layer in timemanager all points remains on the map (not just the first point).
So I guess the question is why self.timeLayerManager.getFrameCount() returns 0... I'll start digg there and see what I can find.

Comment: The problem solved it self in some mystrious way, I tried to add some "print" in the code to see the status of some variables and then everything worked, I removed the rows of code that I added and still working. The problem was probably solved when I reloaded the plugin (I restarted QGIS several times). Hence reload might clean the .pyc file or something?